# How do I safely export c++ data structures from a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll

I am using a pimple idiom to provide an access point for the client to my DLL and to hide all implementation details of `Widget`.

```
class MYCLASS_API MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(ClassData &data);
  ~MyClass();

  void Function1();
  void Function2();

private:
  Widget *p_impl;
};
```

I need to pass non-trivial data to the DLL (I would regularly use STL containers, but I know this is not recommended), so I am providing the `ClassData` structure for being used by the client.

Is that a reasonable approach? If so, how should I design `ClassData`? Since no STL container should be used, would be using raw pointers a viable solution?